# programa de vetor de numero repetido

Tags: c++

preciso criar um vetor que no caso veja quais os numeros repetidos e dê como saida ele, mas se houver 2 valores que tenham a mesma quantidade de repetição a saida tem que ser o de maior valor

meu codigo está assim por enquanto

edit: Não estou sabendo como fazer pra a saida dar o maior valor

ex:

entrada:

6

5 5 5 3 3 3

saida : 3

é o que está dando no meu codigo e precisaria que saisse o 5 porém não sei fazer

```
#include <iostream>
 
 using namespace std;

  int main() {
 

int n,i,nota ;

cin >> n;

int a[n];

for (int i = 0; i< n; i++){
  cin >> a[i];
}

 for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
     for(int j = i+1; j < n; j++)
     {
         if(a[i] == a[j]){
           

           nota = a[j]; 
         
         }

 }
   } cout << nota;

    return 0;


}
```

Comment: Bem vindo @Davidfranca9, seria interessante você nos dizer quais são suas dificuldades e o que está dando errado no seu código para podermos melhor te ajudar. Sua questão esta muito vaga.

Comment: O seu if não deveria ser >  ao invés de ==????

Comment: ja tentei porém da a mesma coisa

Comment: Pelo que entendi sua variável `nota` contém o último número que se repetiu, independente da quantidade de repetições ou de seu valor. A quantidade de repetições importa?

Comment: Também não entendi quando fala de "2 vetores", seu programa trata um único vetor.

Comment: e eram 2 valores nao vetores vou corrigir

Comment: Tem que dar saída do maior, ou do que mais se repetiu? Não entendi

Comment: tem que dar a saida do que mais se repetiu, porém se 2 valores se repetirem igualmente tem que dar a saida do maior valor

Answer (score 0):

Olha se isso te ajuda, está cm Js. Fácil converter para a linguagem que precisar.

```js
var vetor = [5, 2, 5, 3, 2, 2, 5, 4, 3]; //vetor que precisa receber do usuário
var n = 9; // numero de casas do vetor
var nota = 0;
var aux = 0;
var cont = 1;
var contAtual = 1;
var i, j;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) { //usando o método bolha para ordenação. Assim fica mais fácil executar as comparações dos valores.
    for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
        if (vetor[i] < vetor[j]) { // estou ordenando pelo maior
            aux = vetor[i];
            vetor[i] = vetor[j];
            vetor[j] = aux;
        }
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    console.log(vetor[i]); //imprimir vetor ordenado
}

for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    if (vetor[i] == vetor[i - 1]) { //se o valor anterior for igual ao atual.
        cont++; //conta quantos repetiram
        aux = vetor[i - 1]; //salva o valor para verificar o maior
        if ((cont == contAtual && aux > nota) || (contAtual < cont)) { // esse if vc deve entender =>  se o cont atual for igual o anterior que já foi salvo e o valor na nota for maior. Salva o atual. OUUUUU, se o número de cont for maior.
            nota = aux;
            contAtual = cont;
        }
    }
    else { // reseta valores quando o próximo for diferente.
        cont = 1;
        aux = 0;
    }
}
console.log("A maior nota e ", nota);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <title>Hello, World!</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
        <script type="text/javascript" src="contarRepetidos.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```